# Order related element in the view Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have an Album and Picture Models. Album HasMany Pictures. Picture BelongsTo Album. 
I click VIEW on an album, and it shows The Album name, genere, year etc.

And below it shows Related Pictures. So what i want to do is to find a way to sort related picture according a specific column (sort).

**albums** `id | name | genere | year`

**pictures** `id| albim_id | picture | sort .`

This is the find() statement:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Album->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Album not Valid!'));
    }

    $options = array(
        'conditions' =>array(
            'Album.'. $this->Album->primaryKey => $id
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Picture' => array(
                'order' => array(
                    'Picture.sort' => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $this->set('album', $this->Album->find('first', $options));
}
```

but still it doesen't order the picture on ascending order on album view. 
when i do a debug($albums); i get this:

```
'AlbumPictures' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '162',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '14022988892.jpg',
        'sort' => '7',
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '163',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '140229888922sYSpcukDw.jpg',
        'sort' => '1',
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '164',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '1402298889facebook-default-no-profile-pic.jpg',
        'sort' => '4',
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'id' => '165',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '1402298889holder.png',
        'sort' => '5',
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'id' => '167',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '1402298890profile.jpg',
        'sort' => '6',
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        'id' => '170',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '1402298890Untitled-15.png',
        'sort' => '2',
    ),
    (int) 6 => array(
        'id' => '171',
        'album_id' => '80',
        'pic_path' => '1402298890Untitled-17.png',
        'sort' => '3',
    )
)
```

As you see `sort` column is not  in order.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like? And is the [**containable behavior**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) actually enabled on your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well In Your Album Model, where your associations are, you can specify the order of related pictures like this.

**app/Model/Album.php**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Pictures' => array(
        'className' => 'Pictures',
        'foreignKey' => 'album_id',
        'order' => array('sort' => 'asc' ),
    )
);
```

hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My way is more easy custumize for other case:

```
$this->Album->recursive=-1;

$album= $this->Album->find('first',
               array('joins'=>array(array('type'=>'INNER','table'=>'pictures','alias'=>'Picture',
                    'conditions'=>array('Album.id=Picture.album_id','Album.id='.$id))),
                    'order'=>'Picture.sort ASC'));
```